# Open URL from voice trigger with GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying open an URL from home screen with custom voice trigger from home screen. Something like 'ok glass, runABC' and it will open an URL with build in browser.

May i know is this possible with GDK? Sample code or project will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your apps functionality anything beyond opening a website?

Comment: No, my app will just open a website.

Comment: It is feasible ,But I am not sure if the app will get approved by Google,Please give it a check before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. By using a custom voice command, however, do take note that your voice command will need to be approved if you would like to launch your Glassware in MyGlass. For development purposes, it should be fine.

After you've found or set up the appropriate voice command, you can look at [this](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice) on how to create the intent-filter and trigger that will start this voice-activated activity. The link has instructions on how to add prompts to your voice commands (i.e. when you want to go to different URLs for different prompts).

Then you can immediately start an activity that [starts the browser](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser) from the voice-triggered activity.